# scrapy mysql returns empty results

Tags: python, mysql, scrapy, scrapy-pipeline

So my problem is that the information scraped, won't show up in the database.

My spider works fine printing out the information, for example in a .json file.

the pipelines.py

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
  def __init__(self):
   self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.0.2.2", user='root', passwd='', db='mpmf', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
   self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

def process_item(self, item, stack):    
    try:
        self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (pen, name)  
                    VALUES (%s, %s)""", 
                   (item['pen'].encode('utf-8'), item['name'].encode('utf-8')))

    self.conn.commit()


except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])


return item
```

and in settings.py i have added

```
ITEM_PIPELINES = {
'stack.pipelines.MySQLStorePipeline': 300,
}
```

and my log show this errors but you can still see that the information gathering works even though it displays this.

```
 File "/usr/lib/python2.7/dist-packages/twisted/internet/defer.py", line   577, in _runCallbacks
 current.result = callback(current.result, *args, **kw)
 File "/root/stack/stack/pipelines.py", line 14, in process_item
 self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (pen, name) VALUES (%s, %s)""",  (item['pen'].encode('utf-8'), item['name'].encode('utf-8')))
 AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'encode'
```

so no results are imported to the database

Answer (score 0, accepted):

solved it
problem was the indentation and list object had no attribute

```
import sys
import MySQLdb
import hashlib
from scrapy.exceptions import DropItem
from scrapy.http import Request

class MySQLStorePipeline(object):
def __init__(self):
self.conn = MySQLdb.connect(host="10.0.2.2", user='root', passwd='', db='mpmf', charset="utf8", use_unicode=True)
self.cursor = self.conn.cursor()

def process_item(self, item, stack):    
try:
    self.cursor.execute("""INSERT INTO test (pen, name) VALUES (%s, %s)""", (item['pen'][0].encode('utf-8'), item['name'][0].encode('utf-8')))

    self.conn.commit()


except MySQLdb.Error, e:
    print "Error %d: %s" % (e.args[0], e.args[1])


return item
```